# MYSQL to PDO function Call to a member function query() on a non-object

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

my simple function with mysql

```
function sanatciver($id,$deger){
$result=mysql_query("select $deger from sanatci where sanatcino=$id");
$row=mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
return $row["$deger"];
}
```

im new user with pdo

```
$records = $db->select('mp3no, sanatcino')->from('mp3')->where('sanatcino', '=', $sno)->where('onay', '=', 1)->orderBy('mp3no', 'desc')->getAll();
$adet=$db->count();
foreach($records as $record) {
$mp3no              = $record->mp3no;
$sanatcino              = $record->sanatcino;
```

is my sample page is query running succesfuly.

but i want to be write simple functions, it making error Call to a member function query() on a non-object

my sample function

```
function sanatciver($id,$deger){
$result = $db->select('$deger')->from('sanatci')->where('sanatcino', '=', $id)->get();
$xx             = $result->$deger;
return $xx;
}
```

but its making error, how can i do ?

Answer (score -1):

Use global

```
function sanatciver($id,$deger){
    global $db;
    $result = $db->select('$deger')->from('sanatci')->where('sanatcino', '=', $id)->get();
    $xx             = $result->$deger;
    return $xx;
    }
```

Comment: thanks i know this options but my other query get out of order. sample my home page an other pages is broken